# Erro movimentação do player

Tags: java, eclipse

Ola! eu estou tentando fazer o player andar mas sempre quando eu aperto um botão aparece o erro enorme
eu estou tentando fazer o player andar mas aparece esse erro

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Cauã.main.Game.keyPressed(Game.java:136)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6594)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6413)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4893)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Cauã.main.Game.keyReleased(Game.java:155)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6597)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6413)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4893)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)'
```

meu codigo é:

```
<package com.Cauã.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.Cauã.Entity.Entity;
import com.Cauã.Entity.Player;
import com.Cauã.graficos.Spritesheet;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable,KeyListener{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public static JFrame frame;
        private Thread thread;
        private boolean isRunning = true;
        private final int WIDTH = 240;
        private final int HEIGHT = 160;
        private final int SCALE = 3;
        
        private BufferedImage image;
        
        public List<Entity> entities;
        public Spritesheet spritesheet;
        
        public Player player;
        
        public Game() {
            addKeyListener(this);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
            initFlame();
            image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
            spritesheet = new Spritesheet("/spritesheet.png");
            
            Player player = new Player(0,0,19,21,spritesheet.getSprite(39, 0, 19, 21));
            entities.add(player);
            

        }
        public void initFlame() {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(this);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);}
        
        public synchronized void start() {
            thread = new Thread (this);
            isRunning = true;
            thread.start();
        }
        
        public synchronized void stop () {
            
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            Game game = new Game();
            game.start();
        }
            
        public void tick() {
            for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
                Entity e = entities.get(i);
                e.tick();
            }
        }
        
        public void render() {
            BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
            if(bs == null) {
                this.createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;
            }
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
                Entity e = entities.get(i);
                e.render(g);
                }
            g.dispose();
            g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0,WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE,null );
            bs.show();
            
        }
        
        public void run() {
            long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            double amontOfTicks = 60.0;
            double ns = 1000000000 / amontOfTicks;
            double delta = 0;
            int frames = 0;
            double timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(isRunning) {
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                delta+= (now - lastTime) / ns;
                lastTime = now;
                if(delta >= 1) {
                    tick();
                    render();
                    frames++;
                    delta--;
                }
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000) { 
                    System.out.println("FPS: " + frames );
                    frames = 0;
                    timer+=1000;
                }
            }
            
            
        

}

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            
        }
            
        
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ||
                    e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                System.out.println(player);
                player.right = true;
            }
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ||
                    e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                player.left = true;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ||
                    e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                player.up = true;
            }
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ||
                    e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                player.down = true;
            }
        }
        
            

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ||
                    e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                player.right = false;
            }
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ||
                    e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                player.left = false;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ||
                    e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                player.up = false;
            }
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ||
                    e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                player.down = false;
            }
            
        }
        
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        
        
            
        }}

>
```

```
<
package com.Cauã.Entity;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Entity {

    protected double x;
    protected double y;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    
    private BufferedImage sprite;
    
    public Entity(int x, int y, int width, int height,BufferedImage sprite) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }
    
    public int getX() {
        return (int)this.x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return (int)this.y;
    }
    public double getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }
    public double getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }
    
    public void tick() {
        
    }public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(sprite, this.getX(), this.getY(), null);
    }
}
>
```

```
<package com.Cauã.Entity;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Player extends Entity{
    
    public boolean right,up,left,down;
    public double speed = 1.4;
    
    
    public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height, BufferedImage sprite) {
        super(x, y, width, height, sprite);
    }

    public void tick() {
        if(right) 
            x+=speed;
        else if(left)
            x-=speed;
        if(up)
            y+=speed;
        else if(down)
            y-=speed;
    }
}
>
```

```
<package com.Cauã.graficos;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Spritesheet {
    
    private BufferedImage spritesheet;
    
    public Spritesheet(String path) {
        try {
            spritesheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage getSprite(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        return spritesheet.getSubimage( x,  y,  width,  height);
    }
}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi, no meu Game estava :

"Player player = new Player (0,0,19,21,spritesheet.getSprite(39, 0, 19, 21));"

eu tinha que tirar o 1° Player e deixar assim:

"player = new Player (0,0,19,21,spritesheet.getSprite(39, 0, 19, 21));"